# Method open of object workbooks with data properties pop up

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a 8 excel files in a folder. I Want to copy C3 cell value from sheet1 of all excel files.
 I have used following macro for do that

```
Sub Converge_ID()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim i
i = 0
Dim TTFiles_Path As String
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

TTFiles_Path = Range("B1").Value

Set dirObj = mergeObj.GetFolder(TTFiles_Path)
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj

Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
Coverge_ID = Range("C3")

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").Offset(i, 0) = Coverge_ID
i = i + 1
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub.
```

When i executed this macro it works as expected till 8th file. It copies C3 cell value and paste as expected. After closing 8th file, i am getting this pop up.

[image]

How to avoid this error. What causing this error.

Comment: Before you open the file perhaps try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and then after you close it do `APplication.DisplayAlerts = True` to resume normal Excel behavior.

Comment: @DavidZemens: No David, same error

Comment: Note: this is not an **error**.  Perhaps try `Workbooks.Open(everyObj) UpdateLinks:=False`?

Comment: @DavidZemens: Its working correctly for other files. Maybe file Corrupted. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this problem caused by corrupted file.
Its working as per the requirement for other files.